# Execution after .map operator has returned

Tags: angular, rxjs

`SomeService.someMethodverifyEmail()` returns an observable.

**I want the callback inside `setTimeout` to be executed after map has returned**.

Is it possible to get rid of `setTimeout` and use some **RxJs** chaining method to do some operation?

```
SomeService.someMethodverifyEmail()
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          ...
        }, 0);
        return ...;
      }),
      catchError(() => null)
    );
```

P.S. Please do not ask questions like why do you want to do that!

Comment: "Please do not ask questions like why do you want to do that!" Hilarious!

Comment: What do you think `.pipe` is doing?

Comment: Just pipe tap after map, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap`, more infos [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

```js
SomeService.someMethodverifyEmail()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((data) => {
        // This will fires only when someMethodVerifyEmail() has finish
        return this.someService.someOtherMethod(data)
      }),
      catchError(() => null)
    );
```